# Definition of domains in mySQL?

Tags: mysql, attributes, theory

I'm working on a college exercise and have the following question:

> What is the domain of the "country" table?

My understanding of domain is that it defines the possible values of an attribute. 
This means that the table "country" doesn't have a domain, but the various attributes in the table "country" have their own domains.
For example the attribute "SurfaceArea" has the domain `FLOAT(10,2)` and the attribute "Name" has the domain `CHAR(52)`.

Is this correct?

Comment: `country` table? you mean the sample table provided by MySQL?

Comment: Could well be, we were given some databases to work with, one was called "World" and in it is a table called "country", with multiple attributes you would expect to see in a country, size, population, capital city etc... But that's just the example I have, the question stands with any database table, can you use the term "domain" when talking about a table as is done above, or does that specifically relate to individual attributes as is my understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database#Domain

Here is one source and yes, you are correct, domain describes the possible values of an attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding of domains is correct but not complete. Typically, a domain is implemented as a data type like you specified. However, a domain can be more specific than the data type. Consider the attribute Grade, the possible values could be {A, B, C, D, F, I}. If you specify the data type as CHAR(1) then you are not eliminating invalid letters like G, H, J, etc. Consequently, it is important to understand what the original domain is and how it is different from the domain of the data type. Any remaining constraints such as eliminating those invalid values are typically implemented as an application constraints.A good reference on this is Elmasry and Navathe.